# NPM is unexpectedly using an older version of Node

Tags: node.js, npm, version, npm-scripts

When I run `node -v` on my Linux system, I get `v16.7.0` as expected given the installed binaries on my PATH, but when my `package.json` has a `scripts` element including `node -v` which is invoked, it prints `v9.11.2`. **Why is that?**

(The issue was discovered because it also seems to be actually using the older version, which omits features used by a script I want to run, but `-v` is the minimal example.)

When I run `which`/`whereis` `node`/`npm` I get the same result, the expected directory where the binaries are located, which is on my PATH.  In looking through other directories on my PATH, I do not see any node/npm executables.

`echo "$NODE_PATH"` with or without quotes prints a blank line.

I don't see any answers in a `$HOME/.npmrc` file.

Where is it getting Node v9 from, and how can I fix that so that calling `node` from within an npm script invokes a more modern version?

Answer (score 0):

The user's global `node_modules/.bin` folder gets inserted in before the system path, so if [node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) is installed there, it'll be used first.  Using the `npm uninstall -g node` command doesn't necessarily remove it, so you might have to do so manually.

This location can be found out by using the `whereis node` command as part of an npm script, instead of the `node -v` step.